# Feedback - forum review

Tags: discussion, feedback

I've been using various sub-sites of stackoverflow for a little while, but I'm fairly reguarly feeling like I'm missing important bits of culture and could be making better use of the site.  Does stackoverflow have any user feedback mechanism? I'd quite like some process, formal or informal, in which more experienced users could look at my history and give me development points.

Comment: It's called voting ;) If you are getting more than a handful of down-votes you are doing it wrong ;)

Comment: Okay... but is there anything more developmental? I'm kind of looking for a code-review, but on questions rather than code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like on average you're getting [a good number of useful answers and a fair number of up votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170243/joe-reddington?tab=questions&sort=votes) on your posts.  The community has spoken and approves of the content you've been posting :)

This often turns out to be a situation where the squeaky wheel gets the grease (or even an IP ban sometimes).  You haven't been doing anything wrong, so you haven't been the focus of any administrative attention.  And you haven't been doing a *ton* of stuff, so you haven't become a focus of community attention.

You have, however, been contributing good content to the site, which is excellent.

I understand the desire for edification.  You want to make sure you're going in the right direction.  The community doesn't lie (at least not on purpose), so it looks like you are.  Just give it time.  Participate as much as you like, including here on Meta, and it's likely that your contributed content will get better and better.

Keep in mind also that each "sub-site" has and is its own culture.  (A common example is the fact that down-votes mean something different on Meta than they do on Stack Overflow.  As of this writing, you have one down-vote on this question.  That doesn't mean it's a bad question, it just means that someone disagreed with what you're indirectly proposing, a feedback mechanism.)  So don't necessarily take one site's cultural lessons and apply it to another.  Learn each one individually.

But they're just that... cultural lessons.  Only time and experience will develop your involvement within them.

Answer (score 2):

[Scrooge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/scrooge) in a comment and [David](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148400/david) in an answer gave you some great info. I'm just adding something else!

You are using one such mechanism right now, actually... posting here is one way to get some feedback on some specific issue related to your use of the site.

I'm not encouraging you to post every minor question you have looking for feedback. Votes on your posts and reading over things like the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) on each site are your best sources there. But when you have a vital, important, *specific* question about how you are using the site, coming here can be good.

Just as with any other Stack Exchange site, be sure to search first for anything helpful already on the site. Use the feature that offers suggestions when you type your question title as a second-chance search, too. (it uses a slightly different search mechanism. I've actually posted a question here related to that). But if you don't find an existing answer to a vexing question about how you use the site, this can work.

Just keep an open mind :)